# Set up mute/unmute checkbox for the whole app

Tags: java, android, audio, checkbox, android-mediaplayer

Hello I programmed a quiz all works quite fine,  when i check the checkBoxmp Checkbox in the Dialog2, the activity is muted. I set up that when a User fails he will directed to the second activity. There is a Button "restart quiz" which rebrings the user to the main activity. The problem is when I do that the aplication is not anymore muted. Thanks for looking!

**Main Activity**

```
             public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

private TextView mScoreView;
private TextView mQuestionView;
private Button mButtonChoice1;
private Button mButtonChoice2;
private Button mButtonChoice3;
private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionNumber = 0;
Dialog dialog;
Dialog dialog2;
TextView closeButton;
TextView closeButton2;
CheckBox checkBoxmp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.wrong);
    final SharedPreferences sharedPref =getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    boolean isChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("isChecked", false);

        if (isChecked){

        mp.setVolume(0,0);
        mp2.setVolume(0,0);

    }


    else{mp.setVolume(1,1);}

    //Dialog 1
    createDialog();
    Button dialogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //end Dialog 1

    //Dialog 2
    createDialog2();
    Button dialogButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn2);
    dialogButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog2.show();

        }
    });


    closeButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog2.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //end Dialog 2




    //cb


    checkBoxmp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked);
            editor.commit();
        }
    })
    ;


    TextView shareTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share);
    shareTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            myIntent.setType("text/plain");
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello!");
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My highscore in Quizzi is very high! I bet you can't beat me except you are cleverer than me. Download the app now! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=amapps.impossiblequiz");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with:"));
        }
    });

    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();


    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action));
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"

    ((NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1)).setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_stats:
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu3.class));
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
    mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);

    final List<Button> choices = new ArrayList<>();
    choices.add(mButtonChoice1);
    choices.add(mButtonChoice2);
    choices.add(mButtonChoice3);

    updateQuestion();



    for (final Button choice : choices) {
        choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {


                    try {
                        mp.reset();
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                        afd = getAssets().openFd("sample.mp3");
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    updateScore();
                    updateQuestion();
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                } else {
                    mp2.start();
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

private void updateQuestion() {
    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber++);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void updateScore() {
    mScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(++mScore));

    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);

    if (mScore > highScore) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Tutorial");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_1);
    closeButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT);
}


private void createDialog2() {
    dialog2 = new Dialog(this);
    dialog2.setTitle("Settings");
    dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_2);
    closeButton2 = (TextView) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT2);
    checkBoxmp = (CheckBox) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.ckeckBox);


}
```

}

**Menu2 (second Activity)**

```
             public class Menu2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private int mScore;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent =new Intent(Menu2.this,QuizActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2);




    TextView txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore2);
    TextView txtHighScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);

    ImageView trophy1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy1);
    ImageView trophy2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy2);
    ImageView trophy3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy3);
    ImageView trophy4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy4);
    ImageView trophy5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy5);
    ImageView trophy6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy6);
    ImageView genius60Score = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.genius60Img);
    ImageView trophyImgBefore60 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.statsTrophy);




    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mScore = intent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
    txtScore.setText(String.format("Your score: %d", mScore));

    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);



    if (mScore > highScore) {
        highScore = mScore;

        txtHighScore.setText(String.format("High score: %d", mScore));

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);
        editor.apply();
    } else {
        txtHighScore.setText(String.format("High score: %d", highScore));
    }

    if (highScore >= 10) {
        trophy1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (highScore >= 20) {
        trophy2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (highScore >= 30) {
        trophy3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (highScore >= 40) {
        trophy4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (highScore >=50) {
        trophy5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (highScore >= 60) {
        trophy6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        trophyImgBefore60.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        genius60Score.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    final List<ImageView> containers = new ArrayList<>();
    containers.add(trophy1);
    containers.add(trophy2);
    containers.add(trophy3);
    containers.add(trophy4);
    containers.add(trophy5);
    containers.add(trophy6);

    final List<Integer> dialogs = new ArrayList<>();
    dialogs.add(R.layout.popup_menu2_1);
    dialogs.add(R.layout.popup_menu2_2);
    dialogs.add(R.layout.popup_menu2_3);
    dialogs.add(R.layout.popup_menu2_4);
    dialogs.add(R.layout.popup_menu2_5);
    dialogs.add(R.layout.popup_menu2_6);

    for (int i = 0; i < containers.size(); i++) {
        final int j = i;

        containers.get(j).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Menu2.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Trophies");
                dialog.setContentView(dialogs.get(j));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action));
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout2);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv2);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home2:
                    startActivity(new Intent(Menu2.this, QuizActivity.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about2:
                    startActivity(new Intent(Menu2.this, Menu3.class));
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu2.this, QuizActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: If user mute app and go to other activity then go to the mute dialog the checkbox is cheked?

Comment: You should be using a preference activity or maybe just shared preference to store the value.

Comment: As many have stated SharedPreferences is the way to go to store the user settings. BUT, do you really need to open another activity to ask if the user wants to restart the quiz?? Wouldn't an AlertDialog be sufficient?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira can you help me?

Comment: @Alan what is the problem?

Comment: Hello @BrunoFerreira with the code which I updated above the whole app is muted, but if unchecked it should  set volume on

Comment: @Alan in this else `else{mp.setVolume(1,1);}` you only set mp volume and not mp2 I don't know if you want to not set the volume of mp2. But if you want you need to add.

Comment: Yes I forget it

Comment: But with that the soubd is still every time muted

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the status of your check box and read it when initializing the mp, the easy why is  [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) help you at storing the status through all the application even when restarting it.

Declare it like this :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref =getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Adding data and committing it :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);
editor.commit();
```

on the `CheckBox` :

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked);
        editor.commit();
    }
})
```

;

Getting data back a every activity when started :

```
boolean isChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("isChecked", false);
```

Comment: Where should I add this?

Comment: add a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to your `CheckBox`

Comment: So I will remove the onclickistener and instead of it put the setOnChangeListener?

Comment: And where should I put the code of adding data and comiting it and getting data back?

Comment: update my code, yes change the onclick on your checkbox with changelistener and after initialization of mediaPlayer you get the data ad check the value false or true

Comment: Ok i updated the on change listner, now where should i put: SharedPreferences sharedPref =getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); **and** boolean isChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("isChecked", false);?

Comment: the get boolean is in onCreate method

Comment: Sir? doesnot know where to put the mp.set volume code... Check my code i updated it

Comment: after the prefe.getBoolean

Comment: Is my code right I updated my code above if is right i add the setvolume

Comment: i can't see the mp.setVolume ?

Comment: Yes I do not know where to set it up and how?

Comment: Would be very kind if you could tell me how

Comment: unnder     boolean isChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("isChecked", false); put this if (ischecked){ mp.setVolume(0,0)}else{mp.setVolume(1,1)}

Comment: Ok and that under the?

Comment: I tried: if (ischecked){ mp.setVolume(0,0)}else{mp.setVolume(1,1)} it does not work sir. Thereis no audio anymore also when the checkbox is not checked

Comment: I update my code, no audio on my aplication help please

Comment: In my opinion the value of the shardPref should be queried in the `onResume()` Method. When user returns from the second activity `onCreate()` will not be fired.